# Who is speaking to the Philadelphian congregation in Revelation 3:12?

Tags: jesus, revelation, christology

Revelation 3:12 ASV

> He that overcometh, I will make him a pillar in the temple of my God,
> and he shall go out thence no more: and I will write upon him the name
> of my God, and the name of the city of my God, the new Jerusalem,
> which cometh down out of heaven from my God, and mine own new name.

Are the speaker and his God two separate persons?

Answer (score 2):

That Jesus is the speaker (through His chosen representative) in the seven letters in Revelation is evident by comparing the letters.  Note especially:

The greeting to the church in Smyrna:

> These things saith the first and the last, which was dead, and is
> alive; (Revelation 2:8)

The greeting to the church in Thyatira:

> These things saith the Son of God, (Revelation 2:18)

Also compare Revelation 3:3 to Matthew 24:42-44 - it is Jesus who will come as a thief in the night. Other examples from the 7 letters could be cited; the speaker is Jesus.

**References to the Father**

The speaker makes several references to the Father in the letters. For example:

> He that overcometh, the same shall be clothed in white raiment; and I
> will not blot out his name out of the book of life, but I will confess
> his name before my Father, and before his angels. (Revelation 3:5)
>
> To him that overcometh will I grant to sit with me in my throne, even
> as I also overcame, and am set down with my Father in his throne.
> (Revelation 3:21)

These passages clearly reference more than one person.

**Jesus refers to the Father as "my God"**

Not only does He do so in Revelation, Jesus most definitely refers to the Father as "my God" in the Gospel of John:

> Jesus saith unto her, Touch me not; for I am not yet ascended to my
> Father: but go to my brethren, and say unto them, I ascend unto my
> Father, and your Father; and to my God, and your God. (John 20:17)

This implies that the Father is someone else, somewhere else.

**Conclusion**

The speaker is Jesus, and as He does throughout the New Testament, He shows deference in this passage to His Father and God.

*Are the speaker and his God two separate persons?* Yes

Answer (score 1):

**Who is speaking to the Philadelphian congregation in Revelation 3:12?**

The one speaking in these verses to both the congregations in Sardis and Philadelphia is "He who has the seven Spirits of God" and "holds the key of David".

| Rev. 13:1, 7 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup>"And to the angel of the church in Sardis write, 'These things says He **who has the seven Spirits of God** and the seven stars: "I know your works, that you have a name that you are alive, but you are dead. <sup>7</sup>"To the angel of the church in Philadelphia write: These are the words of him who is holy and true, **who holds the key of David. What he opens no one can shut, and what he shuts no one can open**. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

Both refer to prophecies pertaining to our **Lord Jesus Christ**.

| Isa. 11:2 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>2</sup>The Spirit of the LORD shall rest upon Him, the Spirit of wisdom and understanding, the Spirit of counsel and might, the Spirit of knowledge and of the fear of the LORD. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

| Isa. 22:22 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>22</sup>The key of the house of David I will lay on his shoulder; so he shall open, and no one shall shut; and he shall shut, and no one shall open. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

**Are the speaker and his God two separate persons?**

Our Lord Jesus Christ acknowledges someone different from Himself as God, by the words, "My God".

| Rev. 3:12 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>12</sup>He who overcomes, I will make him a pillar in the temple of **My God**, and he shall go out no more. I will write on him the name of **My God** and the name of the city of **My God**, the New Jerusalem, which comes down out of heaven from **My God**. And I will write on him My new name. <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

God refuses to acknowledge someone different from Himself as God, by the words, "Is there a God besides Me? Indeed there is no other Rock; I know not one," and hence, would not refer to anyone as "My God".

| Isa. 44:8 NKJV |
| --- |
| <sup>8</sup>Do not fear, nor be afraid; Have I not told you from that time, and declared it? You are My witnesses. **Is there a God besides Me? Indeed there is no other Rock; I know not one.'**" <sub>(Holy Bible: New King James Version. Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

Therefore, are the speaker and His God two separate beings? **Yes**.

```
p1) GOD does not recognize another person as God;
p2) JESUS does recognize another person as God;
c)  Therefore, JESUS is not GOD.
```